# How to pass data from jQueryUI dialog back to html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have an html form on my site. I'm calling jQueryUI dialog box with three values inside. When I choose one of the values in the dialog box it's going back to the html form, but html is reloading and all other fields are cleared.

How can I pass the data from the dialog without reloading the page and losing the data?

Comment: please post your code already what you done?

Comment: There is form prevent use with `return false` or jquery `event.preventDefault()`  here is some reference for that  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_preventdefault

Answer (score 0):

You can reference an element in the form (for example if you want to update its value), adding a selector in the call back function for the buttons.

In the following example shows how to change the content of a DIV with id `result` when an User click a button in jQuery UI dialog.

Live example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/gibbok/m7gzt32o/

---

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
  modal: true,
  draggable: false,
  resizable: false,
  position: ['center', 'top'],
  show: 'blind',
  hide: 'blind',
  width: 400,
  dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
  buttons: {
    "I've read and understand this": function() {
      // this code s executed when user click the button inside the dialog
      $(this).dialog("close");
      $('#result').text('some info here');
    }
  }
});
```

---

```
body {
  font: normal normal normal 10px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.ui-dialog-osx {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
}
```

---

```
<p>Hello World!
</p>

<form>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="dialog-message" title="Important information">
  <span class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 0 0;"></span></span>
  <div style="margin-left: 23px;">
    <p>
      We're closed during the winter holiday from 21st of December, 2010 until 10th of January 2011.
      <br />
      <br /> Our hotel will reopen at 11th of January 2011.
      <br />
      <br /> Another line which demonstrates the auto height adjustment of the dialog component.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is it :) Thank you for help.

Comment: @MichalT great! I am glad my answer helped you solve your problem. Please do not forget to accept/upvote it using the "tick" icon on the left side of my answer. Thanks for your collaboration and happy coding :)